# Disabling a TextButton

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to disable a TextButton that I've coded as follows:

```
    // Setup new game button
    final TextButton newGameButton = new TextButton("New Game", style);
    newGameButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            Tyr.getInstance().setScreen(new GameScreen());
            AudioHelper.stopMusic();
            return true;
        }
    });
    table.add(newGameButton).spaceBottom(BUTTON_SPACE);
    table.row();
```

However, the "setDisabled(true)" function doesn't seem to be working. Is there some other way that I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found a solution: "newGameButton.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);"

Comment: This just disables us from clicking the button. But how to visually indicate that it is disabled.

Comment: @mcflysoft `TextButtonStyle` has a `disabledFontColor` property on it, you can set it to a different color to visually see the change when you `setDisabled(true)` on the TextButton.